# How to Print Unicode Strings Variably?

Tags: python, unicode

I am relatively new to Python, and I'm currently trying to make a base converter (so that one could enter a number in base 10 and receive an output of that number in hex or binary or so on). To add clarity to my program I've been trying to use unicode data, specifically the characters in `u+208` through `u+209` to print subscript numbers so that the user knows what base a number is in when it is printed.

My code so far is this:

```
import unicodedata

cNum = int(input("Please enter your number: "))

oBase = int(input("Please enter the base you are converting from. "))

nBase = int(input("Please enter the base are you converting to. "))

baseSub = "u'" + "\\u" + str(2080 + nBase) + "'"

baseSub.decode('utf-8')

print(subBase)
```

subBase is the string that I'm trying to convert to unicode, to allow subscript numbers for the new base to be printed (so that if I enter 2 in base ten, the ouput could be printed as 1 with a subscript two). What I have been doing is just writing a bunch of IF statements to check what nBase is 1,2,3,etc. but it is very unwieldy. Normally, to print each subscript the print statement would be (u'`\u208x`') (with x being whatever subscript you want to print form 0-9). The above code is my attempt to create a unicode string that is (u'`\u208x`') with the x being the nBase. Without the decode function, assignment of subBase as "u" + "\u'" ... prints a literal string of u'`\u208x`'. Otherwise there is an error that subBase doesn't have an attribute "decode". How do I get it to print a subscript number from unicode variably, without using a mass of IF statements, if there is a way to at all?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2 in base 10 would be 10 in base 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can convert any number to its subscript codepoints:

```
number = 1234567890
print(''.join(chr(0x2080+int(c)) for c in str(number)))
```

Output:

```
₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₀
```

Note that your output encoding and font need to support the characters, however.

`chr` converts a number to its Unicode equivalent and `U+2080` is a Unicode codepoint in hexadecimal, so you need `0x2080` not `2080`.

Comment: I just tried that and it gave this error:

    print(''.join(chr(0x2080+int(c)) for c in str(number)))
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)

Comment: That's Python 3 code, which I assumed you were using based on calling `print` as a function. `unichr` is the Python 2 equivalent.

Comment: Actually, never mind. It was a typographical error on my part. Thank you for the help!